# gzip css before sending to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp, gzip

How can I Gzip my CSS before sending them to Amazon S3?
I'm using gulp-s3-upload, but I don't really get the documentation, here is my current gulp. For know, It simply uploads the CSS to my bucket, and it's working fine.

```
gulp.task("uploadcss", function() {
    gulp.src('public/css/*.css')
        .pipe(s3({
            Bucket: 'mybucket-assets', //  Required
            ACL:    'public-read'       //  Needs to be user-defined
        }, {
            // S3 Constructor Options, ie:
            maxRetries: 5
        }))
    ;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

ok, it was a stupid question. I had to gzip first with gulp-gzip, then simply add manualContentEncoding: 'gzip'.